# Display Issue with Electrocardiogram on Golang: Unexpected Results Obtained

Tags: go

I'm encountering some difficulty with interpreting an electrocardiogram. Despite my efforts, I'm struggling to comprehend its underlying cause. It appears that I might be incorrectly setting the scale, but I'm also considering the possibility that there could be another reason behind this issue.

```
import (
 "errors"
 "fmt"
 "github.com/fogleman/gg"
 "io/ioutil" 
) 
const (
        Width            = 800
        Height           = 600
        MajorGridSpaces  = 5
        MinorGridSpaces  = MajorGridSpaces * 5
        MinorGridSpacing = Width / float64(MinorGridSpaces)
        SmallSquareSize  = MinorGridSpacing / 5
    )

    encodedData, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/Users/piter/PycharmProjects/ecg/decoded_data.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
        dataStrings := strings.Split(string(encodedData), " ")

    var ecgData []float64

    for i := 0; i < len(dataStrings); i += 13 {
        value, err := strconv.ParseFloat(dataStrings[i], 64)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Eror: %v", err)
        }
        ecgData = append(ecgData, value)
    }

    dc := gg.NewContext(Width, Height)
    dc.SetRGB(1, 1, 1)
    dc.Clear()
    dc.SetRGBA(0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.8)

    for x := 0.0; x <= Width; x += MinorGridSpacing {
        dc.DrawLine(x, 0, x, Height)
    }

    for y := 0.0; y <= Height; y += MinorGridSpacing {
        dc.DrawLine(0, y, Width, y)
    }

    for x := 0.0; x < Width; x += MinorGridSpacing {
        for y := 0.0; y < Height; y += MinorGridSpacing {
            for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
                for j := 0; j < 5; j++ {
                    dc.DrawRectangle(x+float64(i)*SmallSquareSize, y+float64(j)*SmallSquareSize, SmallSquareSize, SmallSquareSize)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    dc.SetLineWidth(0.2)
    dc.Stroke()

    dc.SetRGBA(0, 0, 0, 1)
    dc.SetLineWidth(0.5)

    xStep := Width / float64(len(ecgData)-1)
    for i := 0; i < len(ecgData)-1; i++ {
        x1 := float64(i) * xStep
        y1 := Height/2 - ecgData[i]*(Height/2)/50
        x2 := float64(i+1) * xStep
        y2 := Height/2 - ecgData[i+1]*(Height/2)/50

        dc.DrawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2)
    }
    dc.Stroke()

    if err := dc.SavePNG("ecg_with_grid.png"); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

Supposed to receive

[image]

Instead, receiving

[image]

Example

```
ecgData := []float64{ 0.04878048780487805, -0.06341463414634146, -0.014634146341463415, 0.05609756097560976, -0.01707317073170732, -0.03902439024390244, -0.004878048780487805, -0.01951219512195122, -0.08292682926829269, -0.09268292682926829, -0.06829268292682927, -0.05365853658536585,-0.04878048780487805, -0.06341463414634146, -0.014634146341463415, 0.05609756097560976,-0.01707317073170732, -0.03902439024390244, -0.004878048780487805, -0.024390243902439025, -0.08292682926829269, -0.09268292682926829, ....}
```

Comment: This is difficult to answer without knowledge of the contents of `decoded_data.txt`. Ideally please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (e.g. don't read data from the file, hardcode it using something like `ecgData := []float64{34.5, 10.25, 41.01, 65}`; please also include the `import`s).

Comment: ecgData := []float64{ 0.04878048780487805, -0.06341463414634146, -0.014634146341463415, 0.05609756097560976, -0.01707317073170732, -0.03902439024390244, -0.004878048780487805, -0.01951219512195122,
    -0.08292682926829269, -0.09268292682926829, -0.06829268292682927, -0.05365853658536585,-0.04878048780487805, -0.06341463414634146, -0.014634146341463415, 0.05609756097560976,-0.01707317073170732, -0.03902439024390244, -0.004878048780487805, -0.024390243902439025,
-0.08292682926829269, -0.09268292682926829, ....} and  import (
    "errors""fmt"
    "github.com/fogleman/gg"
    "io/ioutil"
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values you have provided range from -0.092683 to 0.056098; so lets assume the values can potentially be in the range of +/-0.1.

You are calculating the y value with `y1 := Height/2 - ecgData[i]*(Height/2)/50`; lets calculate this for the range above:

```
yMin := 600/2 - -0.1*(600/2)/50 = 300.6
yMax := 600/2 - 0.1*(600/2)/50 = 299.4
```

You will note that these results are very close; this means that the line is going to stay pretty close to the midpoint on the y-axis. It might be more appropriate to use something like:

```
y1 := Height/2 - ecgData[i]/0.1*(Height/2)
y2 := Height/2 - ecgData[i+1]/0.1*(Height/2)
```

With these formulae a graph of your test data would appear as follows:

[image: graph from test data]

Note: If you don't know the min/max possible values you may need to scan through the data to determine this (you need this information in order to determine scaling).